# "for every" or "for any"

Tags: quantifiers

1. For **every** proposition p, (p or not-p) is true.
2. For **any** proposition p, (p or not-p) is true.

The meaning is that "no matter what proposition you put instead of p, (p or not-p) is true.

Which one is a better choice? On the Internet there is more with "any" that with "every". Which is more idiomatic?

Comment: The meaning of "every" and "any" is different. They are not interchangeable. But if you want to say it doesn't matter what proposition you put forward, then use the word **any** e.g. *You can can use **any** name as your username*

Comment: But I think the question really needs a bit more detail, does the "p" stand for "proposition"? If it does, the sentences do not make much sense, if it's only a place holder then use a different letter of the alphabet, any will do.